# Need to add a calculated column for grouping purposes based on data in SELECT statement

Tags: sql

Getting back into SQL after several years away so extremely rusty. I currently have the following result set from a simple table, with 'Type' defined as (H)eader and (D)etails:

| Unique | Description | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CASH | H |
| 2 | 1000 | D |
| 3 | 1100 | D |
| 4 | 1200 | D |
| 5 | FIXED | H |
| 6 | 2000 | D |
| 7 | 2100 | D |
| 8 | 2200 | D |
| 9 | NON-FIXED | H |
| 10 | 3000 | D |
| 11 | 3100 | D |

I need a further column 'Calc' which will evaluate the 'Type' column and return the 'Description' where the 'Type' is 'H', repeating the 'Description' through all the 'D' rows, until such a point that the 'D' changes to 'H' again, whereupon this will be reflected in the result as below. FYI, this is to be used outside of SQL, hence the need to add the grouping.

| Unique | Description | Type | Calc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CASH | H | CASH |
| 2 | 1000 | D | CASH |
| 3 | 1100 | D | CASH |
| 4 | 1200 | D | CASH |
| 5 | FIXED | H | FIXED |
| 6 | 2000 | D | FIXED |
| 7 | 2100 | D | FIXED |
| 8 | 2200 | D | FIXED |
| 9 | NON-FIXED | H | NON-FIXED |
| 10 | 3000 | D | NON-FIXED |
| 11 | 3100 | D | NON-FIXED |

My current query is really very simple:

```sql
SELECT unique, description, type from table
```

So far, I've looked into setting a variable and attempting to set it to the 'Calc' field, but no success. I've also tried combinations of LAG and LEAD but again not leading to any success.

Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which RDBMS and which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

We can use an aggregate function, such as `MAX`, as an analytic function along with the help of a `CASE` expression.  In addition, your requirement is really a gaps and islands problem, since there is no group column to know how to apply the H description.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN Description IN ('CASH', 'FIXED', 'NON-FIXED')
                         THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Unique) AS grp
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *, MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'H' THEN Description END) OVER
              (PARTITION BY grp) AS Calc
FROM cte
ORDER BY Unique;
```

[image: screenshot from demo link below]

### Demo